# Electron.js CLI arguments are not passed to node.js with js-flags

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am creating an app packaged/wrapped via electron.js consisting of a node.js part and some services, and a react frontend.

- Platform: Windows 10 prof.
- Electron version: **19.0.0**
- node.js (embedded): 16.14.2
- chromium (embedded): 102.0.5005.61

I am trying to make the application start with more heap space (more RAM memory assigned). But as far as goes, all efforts are not working.

*Options I tried*:

- passing it as command line arguments with build electron app (e.g.  myapp.exe **--max-old-space-size=4096** or  also --js-flags='--max-old-space-size=4096' )
- passing it via the index.js file that creates the window  (e.g.  **app.commandLine.appendSwitch('js-flags', '--max-old-space-size=4096')**;  )
- passing it directly via the process.env  (process.env["max-old-space-size]=4096)

Everything did not seem to have any effect whatsoever !
(References:   https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2056, https://warpdesign.fr/electron-development-how-to-configure-nodejs-and-runtime-chrome-flags https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-electronjs/  )

The memory **keeps being fixed to 2 GB**  ( output MAX HEAP SIZE (bytes):  2132773076  ~ 1.99 GB )
Also, when outputting what is in the process.env, there is a  NODE_OPTIONS: '--max-old-space-size=4096' ... so in some way it is picked up ???  But never applied to the embedded node.js.

How can I force this to increase it heap space ?  I tried all suggestions. Is that broken in electron ? or am I still doing something wrong ?